# Query works in workbench but not in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to assign a variable a value based on a subquery in the where statement.  The problem is that it doesn't work in php but in the workbench the query runs fine.  I don't get any errors in php and it returns the correct pay ids but the variable field returns empty.

```
SELECT pay_id, @available AS amount_available
FROM tblpayments payments
WHERE customer_id = 9
AND (
    @available := (pay_amount - (
        SELECT if(sum(applied_amount) IS NULL, 0, sum(applied_amount))
        FROM tblxref_pmt_chg xref WHERE xref_pay_id = payments.pay_id
    ))
) > 0
```

Comment: can you post your php code?

Comment: mysql session vars, love it.

Comment: PROTIP: `IFNULL(sum(applied_amount), 0)` :-)

Comment: PROPROTIP: `COALESCE(SUM(applied_amount), 0)` (SQL standard, whereas `IFNULL()` is MySQL specific).

Comment: @eggyal: Forgot about `COALESCE`.  It's actually got another cool feature too.  It accepts infinite parameters and will return the 1st non-`NULL` one! :-D

Comment: Do you really need to use variables (`@available`) here?  Maybe you could convert this into a JOIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try using a JOIN instead of a subquery/variable?

Something like this:

```
SELECT pay_id, (pay_amount - COALESCE(SUM(applied_amount), 0)) AS amount_available
FROM tblpayments payments
LEFT JOIN tblxref_pmt_chg xref ON xref_pay_id = payments.pay_id
WHERE customer_id = 9
GROUP BY payments.pay_id
HAVING amount_available > 0
```

Comment: @eggyal: I guess I need more coffee... `LEFT JOIN` + `COALESCE` is probably the way to go.  Thanks for pointing out my mistakes :)

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat your join idea works perfectly.

Comment: @eggyal `COALESCE` wasn't superfluous now that it's a `LEFT JOIN`. And even before, nothing indicates that `applied_amount` can't be null.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)  Also, thanks to @eggyal for fixing it up :D

Comment: @rsanchez: Whoa.  My bad.  *Eats humble pie*